# FactoryGirl - user/listing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have spent 3 days trying to refactor my rspec tests to incorporate FactoryGirl and feel I need to turn to SO for help.

I have the following:

factories/listings.rb

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :listing do

     title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
     subtitle { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
     description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
     price { Faker::Commerce.price }
     condition { "New" }
     brand { Faker::Company.name }
     model { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
     case_type { "No Case" }
     location { Faker::Address.city }
 end

 trait :les_paul do
   title "1959 Les Paul"
   subtitle "A true gem with OHSC"
   description "Test description"
 end
```

I have also have factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  first_name "Ben"
  last_name "Smith"
  user_name "bensmith"
  password "password"
  password_confirmation "password"
  email "ben@test.com"
end

trait :bob do
  email "bob@test.com"
end
```

end

I then have my feature tests in features/listings_feature_spec.rb:

```
feature 'listings' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
  let!(:listing) { FactoryGirl.create(:listing, :les_paul, user: user, category: category) }
  let!(:user_two) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :bob) }

  ## Lots of passing tests then...

  context 'deleting listings' do
    before { login_as(user) }

    scenario 'removes a listing when the listing owner clicks a delete link' do
      visit listings_path
      click_link '1959 Les Paul'
      expect(current_path).to eq listing_path(listing)
      save_and_open_page
      click_link 'Delete 1959 Les Paul'
      expect(page).not_to have_content '1959 Les Paul'
      expect(current_path).to eq listings_path
      expect(page).to have_content 'Your listing was successfully deleted'
    end
```

This test is failing because of a conditional in the view listings/show.html.erb:

```
 <% if @listing.user == current_user %>
   <%= link_to "Edit #{@listing.title}", edit_listing_path %>
   <%= link_to "Delete #{@listing.title}", listing_path(@listing), method: :delete %>
 <% end %>
```

Here is the test failure....

```
 2) listings deleting listings removes a listing when the listing owner clicks a delete link
 Failure/Error: click_link 'Delete 1959 Les Paul'
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
 Unable to find link "Delete 1959 Les Paul"
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:43:in `block in find'
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:32:in `find'
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:26:in `click_link'
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:698:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
 # /Users/benhawker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/listings_feature_spec.rb:138:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My major questions:
1 - I can see that the user who creates the listing in not the same user who is signed in, in this test. I can validate this as when I run the tests with the save_and_open_page method I can see references to 2 different user_id's. I am missing something here and can't see it.

2 - I should not have to create a user and a category in the listing_feature_spec and then pass it into the let!(:listing). In a previous commit i was working with associations within my factories but this caused all tests to fail with other errors. I would like to understand how to refactor the factories to DRY out my code.

I have include a link to the factories here - https://github.com/benhawker/rails_marketplace/tree/master/spec/factories

Comment: Can you post the test failure?

Comment: @StefanDorunga - I have added the test failure. Thanks for any help!